# Sharepoint 2013 REST API connection using c++

Tags: c++, rest, visual-c++, sharepoint

I am trying to work out how I'm supposed to connect to Sharepoint 2013 using REST calls.  For legacy reasons I have to use WinInet calls from within VC++ 6, I can't use C# libraries or anything like that.

Is there any way to simply prompt a user for their SharePoint username and password with a GET or a POST request, pass this as a REST request, and get an authentication token back?  In fact any guide online for this would be great, but haven't been able to find one.

Anything I've read suggests it isn't, and involves creating authorized apps etc.  If it isn't, I don't understand why it isn't - after all that's what the end user does !